# How to remember window location metacity (Always on visible workspace)

Tags: gnome, metacity

I need to have some applications running on specific workspaces on gnome and have the option (Always on visible workspace) ticked and remembered each time I'm loggin out. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option I know of in Metacity/Marco. There are, however, a handful options to ship around this issue.

- **Compiz:** There is the [Place-Plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place) available which allows you to define placement algorithm and locations.
- **[Devil's Pie 2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/):** The successor to [Devil's Pie](https://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie) allows you to match windows and set certain properties of the window (size, location, abilities and others).
- **Another WM:** You could use a different WM which already allows you to customize the behavior similar, f.e. [Sawfish](http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page).

Given your requirements, your best bet is Devil's Pie, as it will allow you to place the window exactly where you want it.